# Sorry, this video can not be played

Tags: android, video, playback

I am getting string path as below

```
File f = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(File.separator),
        "abc");
File file[] = f.listFiles();
```

and then converting this file array to String array.

```
list = new String[file.length];
for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    list[i] = file[i].getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Now in another class, I am getting these individual elements from list array and passing it to

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://" + list[index]));

String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

Log.d(TAG,"type  = "+type);
intent.setType(type);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

From the above code I am getting `"Sorry, this video can not be played"` error.
I have tried many posts here but could not succeed. Please help in getting through this problem.

Comment: Debug your code and see what you are passing to intent. Check `list[index]`

Comment: list[index] is returning the absolutepath of the file from app folder.

Comment: How big is the video file? It could also be due to a large video file - that's at least what I've experienced myself.

Comment: Size must not be an issue , i have videos of various size starting from less than 1MB to 100MB.None of them is playing successfully. From the logs , it is showing MoviePlayer error for wrong URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me. It ll be very helpful if any one explains the diff.

```
String filePath = data[position];
    Log.d(TAG,"onclick of item position = "+position+" filepAth = "+filePath);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Log.d(TAG,"file = "+file);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
    String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

    Log.d(TAG,"type  = "+type);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```